# The action 'google_oauth2' could not be found for Users::OmniauthCallbacksController

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, omniauth

I'm using 'omniauth-google-oauth2' for sign in with google and follow all instruction here carefully

```
   https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth%3A-Overview
```

but i have error above.

my routes

```
    devise_for :users, :controllers => {
      :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks"

    }
```

devise.rb code

```
  config.omniauth :google_oauth2, "863625299460- 420n6c7lvad91dfvko60uamtvtr6huhf.apps.googleusercontent.com", "dcvA2aZRZi27KCQjWTYP30pw", {  access_type: "offline", approval_prompt: "" }
```

omniauth callback controller code

```
     def google_oauth2
       #@user = User.find_for_google_oauth2(request.env["omniauth.auth"], current_user)
       binding.pry #control not coming here
     end
```

i have error below after callback. see screenshot

```
    https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2/issues/52
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a route issue. If you do "rake routes | grep auth" what do you see?

Comment: i have mtach route but it also not working                             match "/users/auth/google_login/callback" ,:to => "users/omniauth_callbacks#goole_oauth2"

Comment: i see using route grep command                                           user_omniauth_authorize        /users/auth/:provider(.:format)        users/omniauth_callbacks#passthru {:provider=>/google_oauth2/}
  user_omniauth_callback        /users/auth/:action/callback(.:format) users/omniauth_callbacks#(?-mix:google_oauth2)
 user_omniauth_authorize        /users/auth/:provider(.:format)        devise/omniauth_callbacks#passthru {:provider=>/google_oauth2/}
  user_omniauth_callback        /users/auth/:action/callback(.:format) devise/omniauth_callbacks#(?-mix:google_oauth2)

Comment: My error was i don't add this line.                                     devise :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:google_oauth2]

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem you described.  Make sure you require the omniauth-google-oauth2 gem in config/initializers/deviser.rb

```
# ==> OmniAuth
# Add a new OmniAuth provider. Check the wiki for more information on setting
# up on your models and hooks.
require "omniauth-google-oauth2"
config.omniauth :google_oauth2, ENV["GOOGLE_KEY"], ENV["GOOGLE_SECRET"],
                                { access_type: "offline", approval_prompt: "force" }
```

I've added the entire portion of my devise.rb file to provide context.

Answer (score 0):

It's very late but this answer might be useful for others

If you are using `devise` for authentication then devise by default generates routes in the route file `devise_for :users` and your `omniouth_callback` route should be above the default `devise` route so that it overwrites default devise route.

```
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks"}
  devise_for :users
```